# Typedef for pointer to a template class method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

The title sums my question up - I need a generic typedef for a pointer to a template class method, as explained in the code below. The typedef needs to be generic.

```
template<typename TYPE>
struct MyClass {
    const TYPE& get() const {}
};

// this is okay:
typedef void (MyClass<int>::*ParticleMethodPtr)( int );

// now I just need to typedef this so I can
// use the pointer on methods other than int

// using typedef, not okay:
template< TYPE >
typedef void (MyClass<TYPE>::*ParticleMethodPtr)( TYPE );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not allowed, as you've seen yourself.

You can do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct member_pointer
{
    typedef void (MyClass<T>::*function_type)(T);
};
```

Now you can use this as:

```
member_pointer<int>::function_type memfun = &MyClass<int>::some_func;

(obj.*memfun)(100);
```

You can use C++11 template alias to make it simpler as:

```
template<typename T>
using mem_function = typename member_pointer<T>::function_type;
```

then use it as:

```
mem_function<int> memfun = &MyClass<int>::some_func;

(obj.*memfun)(100);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11:

```
template<typename TYPE>
using ParticleMethodPtr = const TYPE&(MyClass<TYPE>::*)() const;

ParticleMethodPtr<int> p = &MyClass<int>::get;
```